# Get all NFTs of an Account on Flow Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, onflow-cadence

Can I get a list of all NFTs to an account on the Flow Blockchain? There is account storage and the [documentation](https://docs.onflow.org/cadence/tutorial/04-non-fungible-tokens/) says

> ...Cadence represents each NFT as a resource object that users store in their accounts...

Or does the respective user has to have a dedicated collection in order to allow others to have a look at their NFTs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain all NFTs under a user account, the following conditions are required:

1. A collection needs to be created under the account to store NFT.
2. The collection provides a public method to query its NFT list.